# Introduction to Analysis: Bisections

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-verification

I feel as though I may be over thinking this problem, at the same time I feel like I may be under thinking it.

> Use a bisection argument to prove that if $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$ is continuous and sup{$f(x)$:$a\leq x \leq b$} = **M**, then $f(c)$ = **M** for some $c$ in $[a,b]$.

I know since f(x) is continuous on the compact interval, the boundedness theorem shows that f(x) is bounded above on I. Thus **M** = $sup_{x\in I}$ $f(x)$. I think the concept applies here, not sure if I can really use the theorem to my advantage.

In this case, my idea was this. For each $a_i$ and $b_i$, always bisect and choose the half which $f$ still satisfies the original hypotheses for $f$ on $[a,b]$.

This is how I was going to go about the proof.

Given $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$ is continuous and bounded above by a supremum, **M**, there must exist a point $c$ $\in$ $I$ such that $f(c)$ = **M**. Given $a\leq x_n \leq b$ for all n, let $I_0$ = $[a,b]$ and given $I_n \subset I_{n-1} \subset ... \subset I$ with $I_n$ = $[a_n,b_n]$ and $a_n\leq x_m \leq b_n$ for infinitely many m, choose $I_{n+1}$ = $[a_n,\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}]$ or $I_{n+1}$ = $[\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}, b_n]$ such that $[f(a_n)+f(\frac{a_n+b_n}{2})]/2$ or  $[f(\frac{a_n+b_n}{2})+f(b_n)]/2$ is closest to **M** for infinitely many m. By the nested interval theorem, there is a unique c inside all these intervals, and lim $a_n = c$ and lim $b_n = c$. Since $f(x)$ is continuous, this implies lim $f(a_n)$ = $f(c)$ = lim $f(b_n).$

This is some idea that I have. The proof is not finished as you can see. I want to say somewhere how the limit of $f(a_n)$ approaches M as $a_n$ approaches $c$ (same goes for $b_n$). Not sure if I really need $[f(\frac{a_n+b_n}{2})+f(b_n)]/2$. Now that I think about it, maybe I should just say what I mentioned earlier before my draft proof, I should just choose the half which satisfies the original hypotheses for $f$ on $[a,b]$. How would I state that though?

Thanks for taking the time to read and Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: You are assuming what you want to prove (see "Given... " above). You are trying to show that a $c$ exists such that $c = \sup f$.

Comment: Please clean up your description of the $I_n$'s.

Answer (score 1):

You have produced a sequence of intervals $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$ such that $a_n \le a_{n+1} \le b_{n+1} \le b_n$,  $(b_{n+1}-a_{n+1}) = \frac{1}{2} (b_n -a_n)$, $I_{n+1} \subset I_n$ and $\sup f([a,b]) = \sup f(I_n)$.

Since $a_n$ and $b_n$ are monotonic, we have $a_n \to \alpha, b_n \to \beta$, and since $(b_n -a_n) \to 0$, we see that $\alpha=\beta$.

Since $\sup f([a,b]) = \sup f(I_n)$, we can choose $c_n \in I_n$ such that $f(c_n) > \sup f([a,b])-\frac{1}{n}$. Note that since $f(c_n) \le \sup f([a,b])$, we have $|f(c_n)-\sup f([a,b])| < \frac{1}{n}$, and so $f(c_n) \to \sup f([a,b])$.

Since $a_n \le c_n \le b_n$, it follows that $c_n \to \alpha$, and by continuity, $f(c_n) \to f(\alpha)$. Since we also have $f(c_n) \to \sup f([a,b])$, it follows that $f(\alpha) = \sup f([a,b])$.